# How to set enabled all radio groups from an Array List in Android?

Tags: java, android, loops, onclicklistener, radio-group

I have created programmatically, a couple of radio groups with 4 radio buttons each. I set OnClickListener on the finish button that i have created too. I want when someone clicks the button, to set all radio groups from the `ArrayList` named `answerGroupList` enabled. How can i do that?
Here is my code:

```
    List<RadioGroup> answerGroupList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<RadioButton> answerList = new ArrayList<>();

    int i = 0;
    for (Question qn : questions) {
        RadioGroup answerGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
        answerGroupList.add(new RadioGroup(this));
        answerGroup.setId(i);
        int j = 0;
        for (Answer an : answers) {
            if (qn.getID() == an.getQuestion_id_answer()) {
                RadioButton answer = new RadioButton(this);
                answerList.add(new RadioButton(this));
                answer.setId(j);
                answer.setText(an.getAnswer());
                answerGroup.addView(answer);
                j++;
            }
        }
        linearLayout.addView(answerGroup);
        i++;
    }

   finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfAnswers; j++) {
                    answerGroupList.get(j).setEnabled(false); // doesn't work
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Edit: Or how to set all radio buttons from the `ArrayList` named `answerList ` enabled?

Comment: Just edit your post, don't add a comment straight after it. Also, what is the stacktrace? "doesn't work" isn't enough info unfortunately

Comment: Sorry but i cannot edit a post after it is sent. It means that nothing is happening when i press the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't enough to use `setEnabled(false)` on an entire `radioGroup`, you have to loop through each item in the `radioGroup` and set each child to `false`.

Integrated into your code would be something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfAnswers; j++) 
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < answerGroupList.get(j).getChildCount(); k++) 
        {
            ((RadioButton) answerGroupList.get(j).getChildAt(k)).setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If i make this changes, it says `variable 'answerGroupList' is accessed from within inner class needs to be declared final `. If i declare it as final, i get this error: `cannot resolve method getChildAt(k)`.

Comment: Uusally this means that if two methods see the same local variable, Java wants you to not to change it. However, you probably don't want this. Try making it a global variable instead.

Comment: I just tried to set the variable `answerGroupList` global like this, `public ArrayList<RadioGroup> answerGroupList;` but it doesn't work. Same problem. Were am i wrong?

Comment: Can I just check that you declared it at class-level and not within the method? This also goes for trying to change it to final

Comment: I've another change. I declared the variable as global like this: `List<RadioGroup> answerGroupList = new ArrayList<>();`. When i turn on the app, nothing happen. The radio buttons remain enable.

Comment: So you aren't getting an error anymore, just nothing happens?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see if it is looking at the correct radiogroup and children?

Comment: Yes, no errors, just nothing happens. This is what i am trying to do, to figure it out if it is looking at the correct radio group and children but nothing found yet.

Comment: Do you know how to debug/step through code? If not it would be worth doing this. You can set up a breakpoint, and then look at what each variable holds.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know how to debug/step through code. I will learn for sure but for the moment i just make some tests.

Comment: It's definitely an essential technique in programming :) It will allow you to see if they were set up correctly in the first place. Something that you could try doing is casting to a RadioButton. So something like:
`(RadioButton) answerGroupList.get(j).getChildAt(k).setEnabled(false);`

Comment: You may have to change the variable to `final`

Comment: I think correct it's like this: `((RadioButton) answerGroupList.get(j).getChildAt(k)).setEnabled(false);`. With this change and with variable final, nothing happens.

Comment: That's correct. You will need to step through the code to identify where you went wrong in setting everything up. The code I provided should work fine :)

Comment: I will try to make exactly as you say and i will came back with an answer.

Comment: Yes, for sure i'll do.